# Сборка билда игры в UNITY

Tags: c#, unity3d, xml

У меня есть небольшой тестовый прототип игры от третьего лица. В нём происходит сохранение прогресса в XML-файл, а также чтение из другого XML-файла с диалогами и прочим. Проблема состоит в том, что после сборки игра не работает (нет этих самых файлов XML). Я пробовал вставлять их в папу с игрой, но эффекта не было.
Есть ли способ добавить эти файлы ы сборку или другое решение данной проблемы?

Вот методы работы с XML-файлами

```
 void GetEnemyIndex()
    {
        /* Открытие и чтение данных из XML-файла */
        string XMLpath = Application.dataPath + "/Progres.xml";
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(XMLpath);
        XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Progres");
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            _enemyIndex = int.Parse(node["Index"].InnerText);
        }

        if  (_enemyIndex > 4)
        {
            _enemyIndex =  0;
        }
    }

    void GetEnemyText(int index)
    {
        string XMLpath = Application.dataPath + "/Text.xml";
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(XMLpath);
        XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("HISTORYTEXT");
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            text += node[enemy[index]].InnerText;
        }
        Debug.Log(text);
    }

    void SaveProgres()
    {
        string XMLpath = Application.dataPath + "/Progres.xml";
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(XMLpath);
        XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Progres");
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            node["Index"].InnerText = (_enemyIndex + 1).ToString();
        }
        xmlDoc.Save(XMLpath);
    }
```

Comment: Зависит от платформы, на мобильниках вообще нужно работать с `Application.persistentDataPath`.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение: вместо `Aplication.dataPath` использовать нужно `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

Comment: Если вы сами ответили на свой вопрос, пожалуйста, отметьте свой ответ как "правильный", чтобы закрыть вопрос